# read_only vs const on non-image OpenCL parameters

Tags: opencl, readonly, qualifiers

Reading the OpenCL documentation, I know that the access qualifiers [`read_only` and `write_only` are intended for image memory](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/accessQualifiers.html).

However, I'm noticing some people use these qualifiers on regular, non-image-memory, parameters, e.g.:

```
void foo(unsigned n, __global read_only int* data)
```

Note the lack of `const`.

My questions:

1. Does `read_only` imply, in particular, `const`?
2. Does `read_only` imply anything *other* than `const`? Something else that an OpenCL compiler can utilize?

... or is it just meaningless for non-image-memory, and ignored?